# I need limited nested array in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document like

```
{
    "deviceId" : "1106",
    "orgId" : "5ffe9fe1c9e77c0006f0aad3",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "paramVal" : 105.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T09:18:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "paramVal" : 110.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T09:18:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "paramVal" : 115.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T10:18:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "paramVal" : 125.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T11:18:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "paramVal" : 135.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T12:18:08.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to filter a document which I can do easily with match or find but in that document the subarray i.e. values should have latest 2 values because in future the count can be more than 100.

the output should be like

```
{
    "deviceId" : "1106",
    "orgId" : "5ffe9fe1c9e77c0006f0aad3",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "paramVal" : 125.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T11:18:08.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "paramVal" : 135.0,
            "dateTime" : ISODate("2021-05-05T12:18:08.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) operator, to select number of elements, pass negative value to select documents from below/last elements,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { values: { $slice: ["$values", -2] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6J8FGxg-QEJ)

---

> *I need for the array values in sorted order by date*

There is no straight way to do this, check the below aggregation query, but it will cause the performance issues, i would suggest to change you schema structure to manage this data order by date,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `values` array
- `$sort` by `dateTime` in descending order
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `values` array and return other required fields
- `$slice` to select number of elements, pass negative value to select documents from below/last elements

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$values" },
  { $sort: { "values.dateTime": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      deviceId: { $first: "$deviceId" },
      orgId: { $first: "$orgId" },
      values: { $push: "$values" }
    }
  },
  { $set: { values: { $slice: ["$values", 2] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bS7Az9Nkoyu)

Comment: Thank you  but I need for the array values in sorted order by date

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      values: {
        
          $sort: {
            createdDate: -1
          },
          $slice: [
            "$values",
            -2
          ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: something like this